# Not able to install npm lite server

Tags: node.js, npm, server

When I ran the command `npm install -g lite-server` I got the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/lite-server failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND your-proxy-url
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\danis\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-27T06_03_24_424Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: This seems like an issue on your side, I was able to install it with that command just fine. Make sure that you have no weird configurations or proxies enabled that could potentially be impacting your ability to install NPM packages.